# How to move a row in the last cell of the row before Excel csv

Tags: excel, function, csv, data-cleaning

I hope someone knows a good excel function to solve my Problem because I just can't figure out how to do it.

I have my CSV Data for examle like this:

```
id, geodata, hashtag, text 
id, geodata, hashtag, text 
id, geodata, hashtag, text 
text 
id, geodata, hashtag, text 
id, geodata, hashtag, text 
text, text 
text 
text 
id, geodata, hashtag, text 
id, geodata, hashtag, text 
id, geodata, hashtag, text 
text
```

Now the Problem as you see is that some of the text Data had a break (or even more) and it came to the next row. Because I have a lot of this Data and I cant check all of it, is there any way how could i get the "breaked" text to the cell of the text in the upper row for every single case???

Thanx for help

Comment: cant u set your delimeter as comma instead of space or tab

Comment: Its easy enough to find the text on the row above but how are you going to decide logically if it is indeed broken, are the id's in a format that can be recognized easily using logic?, is there some sort of marker breaking this data up? is it possible some text might match a hashtag? this kind of fix is never guaranteed to be 100% correct. where is this data breaking Excel or is it already broken on the CSV? if the CSV is not broken i recommend manually extracting the data using code and not using excels csv converter. or remove these bad characters and whitespaces first before importing it.

Comment: Removing is not a problem but i would like to concat them with the upper text cell. The data was from the begining like that. The id is numeric, but still i dont know how to make a loop that tell it to concat the text with the upper one for every case